# Call a method multiple times by using a thread

Tags: multithreading, spring

I have a controller class in spring MVC which has one method (`executeBatch()`) that calls long batch execution methods on other classes. These executions takes long time, some times hours. The `executeBatch()` method is annotated with `RequestMapping` to an ajax call in client side.

Now, I want to call this method from client side before it completes its previous batch execution. So that, two/more batch execution can happen simultaneously on two/more threads.

Can I implement threading (I mean create new thread in every new request to that method) in this scenario and how?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to annotate your service method with @Async . If you have a global executor service defined then this will be executed using that executor which would also take care of limiting the total number of parallel batch jobs to not overwhelm the system with requests.

Details can be found here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/